# When using JSON in Fragments the app is not responding in Android Development

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I'm using navigation drawer in android. I have got the data from a URL through JSON. When I run the app when it loads the fragment there's an error saying

> "Unfortunately the App has not responded "
>   I'm getting the JSON Data from a PHP file and it is taken from the INTERNET for now it is in the localhost.

My Fragment class is :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class QMFragment extends Fragment {



public QMFragment(){}

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://localhost/app/qm_data.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_QM = "qm";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_URL = "url";

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // JSONArray
    JSONArray qmArray = null;

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qm, container, false);


        getData(); 


        return rootView;
    }

    public void getData(){
        try {
            // Getting Array
            qmArray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QM);

            // looping through All Data
            for(int i = 0; i < qmArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = qmArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String url = c.getString(TAG_URL);

             // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_URL, url);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and my JSONParser.java is :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error Converting Result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error Parsing Data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

and my XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/head"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigate_RLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtqmhead"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/qm_heading"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtqmsub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/qm_chn"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtqmhead"
                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp" />

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtqmsub"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >


             </TableLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the PHP File is :

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "test";


$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$username,$password);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($db, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY date DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
        $output['qm'][]=$row;
  }

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

The LogCat:

```
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.qrodsintegrated.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:38)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.qrodsintegrated.QMFragment.<init>(QMFragment.java:41)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.qrodsintegrated.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:175)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.qrodsintegrated.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:164)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.qrodsintegrated.MainActivity$SlideMenuClickListener.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:126)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-24 10:19:54.322: E/AndroidRuntime(1700):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to check your debug logs and post the exception stack trace.

Comment: Seems yoiu are running network related operation on the ui thread. suspect `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. post the stack trace

Comment: So what should I do in it. to make it work?

Comment: Use a `Thread` or `AsyncTask`

Comment: Can you rewrite this with that and help me because I used it once and got the whole app not responding and the data was not parsed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
```

And in `JSONParser`

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Running NetworkRelated operation on the ui thread.

Use `AsyncTask` or `Thread`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
 new TheTask().execute(params);
```

Then

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    protected void doInbackground(Void... params)
    {
       // your http request
      return null;
    }
}
```

You can make asynctask an inner class of fragment and update ui in `onPostExecute`

Edit:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qm, container, false);
    new TheTask().execute(url);
    return rootView;
}
```

Then

```
 class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    @override
    protected String doInbackground(String... params)
    {
        String _response =null;
        try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         _response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
           e.printStacktrace();
        } 
      return _response;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.i(".......",result);

}

}
```

Comment: Thank You. I'll do as you told me and get back with you.

Comment: I get this now 12-24 11:07:04.802: W/dalvikvm(1848): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)

Comment: 12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at com.qrodsintegrated.QMFragment$TheTask.onPostExecute(QMFragment.java:122)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at com.qrodsintegrated.QMFragment$TheTask.onPostExecute(QMFragment.java:1)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
12-24 11:07:04.822: E/AndroidRuntime(1848):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)

Comment: @Ruch1234 your `Log` needs a value since the value is null you get that exception

Comment: Ohh ok what kind of value does it need?

Comment: @Ruch1234 a string in your case ie the result of json. but if its null you get NPE

Comment: But still the error message shows "Unfortunately the app is not responding"

Comment: In the postExecute how to add new textview dynamically. I did it. Then the error comes again. before that it was working fine

Comment: @Ruch1234 you can declare textview as a instance variable. initialize it in onCreateView. have text view in layout. Then update textview in onPostExecute. Make sure asynctask is an inner class of fragment

Comment: Everything is working fine. but the array gets doubled in some places as in if the first value is 'dog' after few values another value called 'dog' comes. So how to solve that ?

Comment: @Ruch1234 post a new question with relevant details.i am sure your problem can be solved

Comment: Ohh is that so. I check whether there is any errors and see if its not ok i will post a question. Thank You

Comment: @Ruch1234 since this post already has a accepted answer it is not good to edit it further. New problem post a new Question. If not me there are others many talented and your problem will be resolved soon

Answer (score 4):

Write this in your onCreate

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

for api level >9

and also use async task for parsing values

Comment: no this is not recommended. If you are testing then ok. All network related operation must be done in a background thread